# Will integrating nuxt.js into our vue.js application require much overhaul?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm considering integrating nuxt.js into our vue.js application. I'm trying to figure out if it's feasible. By feasible, I mean how much of an overhaul would it require.

I understand that nuxt.js is more than just a pluggin. If it were a plugging, it would be super easy. You would just npm install and Vue.use(nuxt) and that's it. But as a framework, I understand that nuxt.js expects certain structures to be in place. For example, I know from https://hiswe.github.io/2018/12-vue-with-nuxt/ that nuxt expects a certain folder structure (/static, /page, /layouts...), but can these live side-by-side with the standard vue.js folders (/assets, /components, /views...) or do they have to be replaced? If side-by-side, then no overhauling of existing code (just add new folders). Otherwise, there could be quite a bit of work to overhaul the structure.

And if they can live side-by-side, would the nuxt folder supersede the vue.js folders (ex. would it no longer look for components in /components or /views and instead expect them to be in /pages)?

I also understand that nuxt router depends only on the folder/file structure in /pages rather than the router.js file that vue.js depends on. Does this mean router.js will no longer be used? Or will router.js still be used until we tell it not to (by removing certain routes from it, for example).

You don't need to answer the above questions (although it would be super useful if you did). I just provide them to give an example of the things I need to consider. The main question is: how much work is involved in overhauling a vue.js application when nuxt.js is being integrated.

To give some perspective of the size/complexity of our application, you can see it here:

https://www.bodecanada.com/

The source code is just under 600MB (compared to a startup vue.js application which is usually < 100MB). It includes a backend API that connects to a postgres database. We host it on AWS Lambda. We'd like to take advantage of the SSR abilities of nuxt.js but as I understand it, that requires a node.js server (not sure how easily that integrates with our Lambda instance).

^ Those are the specs. Just looking for a rough idea. Easy? Difficult? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: 600MB source code?

Comment: yep. Includes images, node_modules, etc.

Comment: how big is it without those, since that number is pretty useless

Comment: Minus node_modules, minus assets, 262.5MB.